# How to use the jQuery DataTables API in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to grasp how the DataTables API works. Therefore, I would like to execute some simple calls in the Chrome Dev Tools and see the result live.

Imagine you have a simple table with headings Foo and Bar:

```
---------
|Foo|Bar|
---------
|1  |a  |
---------
|2  |b  |
---------
```

In Chrome Dev tools I would like to do the following:

```
var table = $('.datatable').DataTable();
table.search('a').draw();
```

After that only the first row should appear. However, this doesn't work. I also tried to use `$('.datatable').dataTable().api();` instead of  `$('.datatable').DataTable();`, but still couldn't get it work. Any idea how this can be accomplished?

Comment: please paste also your html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must inject each script individually, initialise the dataTable and then you can use [**`$_`**](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#_) as reference to the dataTable API :

1. inject jQuery :

   ```
   var s = document.createElement('script');
   s.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
   ```

Wait until the console responds :

```
<script src=​"/​/​ajax.googleapis.com/​ajax/​libs/​jquery/​2.1.4/​jquery.min.js">​</script>​
```

2. inject dataTables :

   ```
   var s = document.createElement('script');
   s.src ="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.js";
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
   ```

Wait until the console responds :

```
<script src=​"https:​/​/​cdn.datatables.net/​1.10.9/​js/​jquery.dataTables.js">​</script>​
```

3. initialise your table :

   ```
   jQuery('.dataTable').DataTable();
   ```

The console will respond with :

```
[]
```

4. You can now play with the API for the initialised dataTable using `$_` :

   ```
   $_.search('a').draw();
   $_.search('').draw();
   $_.column(1).visible(false);
   ```

....and so on. But somehow I think a fiddle is more convenient as playground -> **http://jsfiddle.net/j92jh4fo/** :)

Comment: O.K., I little twist here - I am trying to do this in Rails project, so I already have all the scripts loaded and the datatable is initialized, when I load the page. However, you gave an accurate answer to my question, so I am accepting it.